# PHP mysqli won't insert data into table

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm new to using mysqli_stmt statements in PHP. No matter, what I try, I can't insert data into my table. I have 2 tables, one, I can insert the data in but this one does not work

```
if ($new_profile_query = mysqli_prepare($db, 
       "INSERT INTO profile (
             uid, 
             first_name, 
             last_name, 
             biography, 
             interests, 
             date_of_birth) VALUES (
              ?, 
              ?, 
              ?, 
              ?, 
              ?, 
              ?)")) {
//VALUES ('$user_numberr', '$fname', '$lname', '$biography', '$interests', '$dob')";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($new_profile_query, 
     "issbbs", 
      $user_numberr, 
      $fname, 
      $lname, 
      $biography, 
      $interests, 
      $dob);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($new_profile_query);
   mysqli_stmt_close($new_profile_query);
}
```

Comment: is this a typo `$user_numberr` -double r?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Can you also show the table schema?

Comment: No the double r is not a typo

Comment: I don't get an error, it just won't upload anything to the table. I have 2 tables on the same account. It uploads to one, but not the other

Comment: try entering the data in db through a GUI, phpMyAdmin suppose. Does it insert the data?

Comment: @PrerakSola I can do that, but it won't send through this

Comment: Do you really insert blobs?From the col names strings could be suitable.

Comment: can you show the table schema?

Comment: @Mihai I've already tried string. From my understanding, a blob is a big string. It didn't work with a string, and not with a blob either.

Comment: @PrerakSola I'm sorry, what does schema mean?

Comment: There must be an error  show it to us **mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);**

Comment: Your table structure. The one you get by `Desc [table_name]`

Comment: or add this at the end yr of script `die("Error:".mysqli_error())`  or `die("Error:".mysql_error())`

Comment: @animaacija After doing that, I get a whole bunch of errors

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() [function.mysqli-stmt-execute]: Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt

Comment: I get an error for execute, bind result, and close

Comment: well, just paste all your errors [here](http://notepad.cc) and give here a link. Do you pass variables to database class?

Comment: http://notepad.cc/share/QFXhyPwGrj

Comment: @animaacija http://notepad.cc/share/QFXhyPwGrj

Comment: [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2512400/2644170) the socond insert not working, cos first one closed stmt. Is this so?

Comment: @animaacija I kind of got rid of that problem somehow, but I have a different problem now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488768/undefined-function-mysqli-stmt-init-php-error