# How to fix "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmnt_init()" in PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

When I tried to execute it, it says:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmnt_init()

```
else{

    $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM user WHERE uidUsers=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmnt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        if($resultCheck > 0){
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
            exit();
        }
        else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmnt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit();
            }
```

Comment: you have a typo mistake, should be: `mysqli_stmt_init()`

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488768/undefined-function-mysqli-stmt-init-php-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined function mysqli\_stmt\_init() php error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488768/undefined-function-mysqli-stmt-init-php-error)

Comment: Thank you so much it was so careless of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above. You have a typo, the actual function call should be mysqli_stmt_init() whereas you have mysqli_stmnt_init().